# datastax opscenter 'API' metrics error

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I am using datastax opscenter api to retrive metrics through python script and trying to match the results with the graphs on opscenter
While I  am trying to to get data for 'TBL : LiveDisk  Used' as you can see in the graph below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk3ec.png)

function in python script is as follows :

```
def diskUsage(url11, cluster_id, start_time, end_time, node_ip1):
        p = {'metrics': 'cf-live-disk-used',  
             'columnfamilies': 'all', 
             'nodes': node_ip1,
             'step': '120',
             'start': start_time,
             'end': end_time }
        url="http://"+url11+"/"+cluster_id+"/metrics/"+node_ip1+"/cf-live-disk-used"
        MetricSingleNode = session.get(url, params=p)
        DataC = json.loads(MetricSingleNode.content)
        print "DataC is ", DataC
```

Output:

```
DataC is  {u'{node_ip}': {u'MAX': [[1469930400, None]], 
                          u'AVERAGE': [[1469930400, None]], 
                          u'MIN': [[1469930400, None]]
                         }
          }
```

Why the output is none while opscenter is giving the data?

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, opscenter is reading the 1 minute period metrics. Your query is pulling the 2 hour period which may not have data in your start/end range (yet). Try running with `step:1`.

Comment: chris if I do that it is giving the following output: DataC is  {u'{node_ip}': {u'MAX': [[1469934900, None], [1469935200, None], [1469935500, None]], u'AVERAGE': [[1469934900, None], [1469935200, None], [1469935500, None]], u'MIN': [[1469934900, None], [1469935200, None], [1469935500, None]]}}